# Typescript force implementation of optional interface members

Tags: typescript

Given an interface

```
interface IAmOptional {
   optional? : string,
   optional2?: string
   forced: string
}
```

Is there a way to covert, extend or similar `IAmOptional` in a way that this implementation fails?

```
class someClass {
    thisShouldHaveAllKeys : IAmOptional  = { // Forced<IAmOptional> ??
        forced: 'i am forced'
    }  // Here I want an error like 'thisShouldHaveAllKeys does not have optional and optional2' 
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, starting with TypeScript 2.8 there is a way to [programmatically remove the optional modifier from properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers) using the `-?` syntax with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type Required<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] }
```

This gives you the behavior your want:

```
class someClass {
  thisShouldHaveAllKeys: Required<IAmOptional> = {  // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- missing properties optional1, optional2
    forced: 'i am forced'
  }
}
```

In fact, this `Required` type alias is so useful that it's [predefined for you in the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1418-L1423).  So you can just use it without defining it.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a second interface to override the optional members:

```
interface IAmOptional {
  optional? : string,
  optional2?: string
  forced: string
}

interface IAmNotOptional extends IAmOptional {
  optional: string;
  optional2: string;
}
```

It's not very elegant but it does the trick. An alternative approach is to turn the problem upside down and make use of Typescript's `Partial` feature:

```
interface IAmNotOptional {
  optional: string;
  optional2: string;
  forced: string;
}

class A {
  all: IAmNotOptional = { forced: 'forced' }; // error
  some: Partial<IAmNotOptional> = { forced: 'forced' }; // no error
  none: Partial<IAmNotOptional> = { }; // no error, but perhaps undesirable behaviour
}
```